# hosting ASP.NET MVC 4 web api on IIS - failed to load resource

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, iis, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to set up an API and test it, (but my knowledge of ASP.NET MVC and IIS are limited). I'm using the sample code provided at http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis (Sample: Contact Manager).

I uploaded all the provided files from the ContactManager folder (App_Data, Content, etc.) and then set up a new website in IIS with the IP 142.70.43.211 and the Home Directory pointing to the local directory containing the files.

The Default.htm file loads fine, but the Jquery ajax call returns an error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (not found)".

At first, I thought it was the fact that the jquery get() call is requesting just "contacts" rather than the complete url, but Chrome's Console shows me it is trying to load "142.70.43.211/contacts" and failing...

EDIT: I forgot to upload the "packages" folder that was provided...after doing this, the console gives me the error: "GET 142.70.43.211/contacts 404 (Not Found)"...not much different...

Did I miss a step in setting something up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [WebApiConfig.cs](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Contact-Manager-Web-API-0e8e373d/sourcecode?fileId=60331&pathId=1438156725) file shows the routes defined as follows:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( 
    name: "DefaultApi", 
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}", 
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional } 
);
```

Which means its expecting /142.70.43.211/**api**/contacts.  Check if Views\Home\Index.html has reference to the paths "api/contacts" and not just "contacts"

Answer (score 0):

I was getting 404 errors until I went to the IIS manager for the site -> Basic Settings, and changed the application pool to "ASP.NET v4.0".